# Lookup column output includes strange characters

Tags: 2013, email, workflow-activity

I have a lookup column ("Title"), that returns as text, which it looks-up from a different library (obviously).

I have a workflow that emails the user when the list item is created, and in that email, I have included the Title field. However, the email is showing the contents of the Title field along with other characters - an example is:

The column in the list says .

The column in the email says 3;#3.

My environment is SharePoint 2013 and I am using a SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Why is it adding the additional characters to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some looking around, the way to fix this issue is to return the value as a 'Lookup Value (as Text)' as shown below

[image]